# How to use rowspan in WP List Table?

Tags: wp-list-table

I can use WP_List_Table class as just a simple list.
But, I want to use a rowspan or colspan which is a default feature of html table.

How to apply rowspan or colspan?

Comment: If you're just doing a simple list, why do you need the WP_List_Table class? Couldn't you just use the same classes/markup on an HTML table?

Comment: Umm, I want to use that class for Consistency.

Answer (score 0):

I extended WP_List_Table to My_Custom_List_Table class and customize My_Custom_List_Table for my purpose.

Specially, `function single_row_columns()` and `function display_rows_or_placeholder()`.

And, not echo some td tag for other main td tag that have rowspan.

All process was not such difficult.